# Where can I find Invictus Oaths?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, vampire-the-requiem

I have been searching the Internet for Invictus Oaths, and believe that I am running into a bunch of jacked up homebrew ones. Is there anyway that someone could give me a list or a good book to read up on actual Invictus Oaths? They would be being used in a nWoD Requiem Mind's Eye Society game!

Comment: These questions have prompted [a Meta discussion about how we tag WoD questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2880/shall-we-review-the-various-world-of-darkness-tags-use). Regular users interested in tagging issues, please chime in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Invictus sourcebook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1588462595) is probably the best place to find (official) oaths.

It contains the following oaths:

- Blood-Tell Oath
- Oath of Blood Knives
- The Oath Unsworn
- Oath of Burning Blood
- Oath of Running Blood
- Oath of the Bloody Hand
- Oath of Blood Focus
- Oath of Blood Alliance
- Oath of Blood Service
- Oath of Blood Loyalty